# Restricting router bandwidth for others only when I need it

Tags: tomato

I work from home and I want to restrict bandwidth for the other computers in my home, but only when I need it. Otherwise, let them take all they want. All I can see is ways to restrict their bandwidth all the time.

For example, let my living room computer take all the Netflix bandwidth it needs when I'm not using my computer, but restrict it when I'm on Skype (or whatever).

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "router bandwidth". Are you talking about the actual capacity of the router to forward traffic? Or do you really mean WiFi bandwidth? Or do you mean inbound Internet bandwidth? These are all completely different problems with completely different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Look up QOS. You define priorites for various processes/applications and the bandwidth will throttle accordingly.

Your router might not support it; in which case, I recommend checking out open source ware.. eg. tomato usb/dd-wrt and so forth.

Comment: Assuming he wants to protect his inbound Internet bandwidth, QoS won't help. The soonest he could apply QoS is when he's received a packet, and by then it's already consumed that bandwidth.

Comment: This is mostly a myth. Inbound QoS has improved to a point where it is highly effective in almost every scenario (with latest Shibby or Toastman firmware)

In my experience though, setting up QoS requires a lengthy experimentation phase. Think weeks, not days or hours. My Guide is here.  http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/using-qos-tutorial-and-discussion.28349/page-11#post-229534